# Correspondence between fractal sets and trees

Tags: fractals, trees, ergodic-theory

In Hillel Furstenberg's series lectures on ergodic theory in fractal geometry, he mentioned his search on finding a one-to-one correspondence between fractal sets and trees, however, I couldn't not find any material online about this. Does anyone have reference on that?

Comment: Cross-posted (under the name Rob): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422449/correspondence-between-fractal-sets-and-trees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fractals and trees can be connected through the machinery of CP-processes, which are a kind of discrete-time version of the scenery flow. This has been studied intensively in the last few years by my colleague Pablo Shmerkin and coauthors: I think that the paper "Local entropy averages and projections of fractal measures" by Hochman and Shmerkin should contain enough references to help you find what you're interested in.

Comment: offhand: Has anyone restated the scenery flow material in the language of sheaves?